# Free Input not working on bootstrap typeahead

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead

Please review below code

```
var elt = $('input');
  elt.tagsinput({
  itemValue: 'value',
  itemText: 'text',
   freeInput: true,
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'cities',
    displayKey: 'text',
    source: cities.ttAdapter()
  }  
});
```

Comment: var states=[{ "value": 1, "text": "Amsterdam", "continent": "Europe"},
{ "value": 2 , "text": "London", "continent": "Europe"}];var cities = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  //prefetch: 'https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/cities.json'
  local:states
});
cities.initialize();

Comment: Please help me to fix this issue